# Json_encode in While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I need to get data from the database with ajax and put that data in the 'select' tag. I need to have every name in a different 'option'... View the code:

Index.php:

```
<label>Select:</label>
<select id="users"></select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("frombase.php", function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var id in data) {
            $("#users").empty();
            $("#users").append("<option value='"+ id +"'>"+ data[id] +"</option>")
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

});

And frombase.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$name = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$name[] = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode(array("name" => $name));

mysqli_close($db);
```

Look at the result (I do not need this)

[image]

(My english is not good, because I use Google Translate)

Comment: Just do `echo json_encode($name);`. There's no need to put it in another array. Or if you want to keep it as is, then in your JS, do: `for (var id in data.name])` and then `+ data.name[id] + `.

Comment: Or change JS loop to `for (var id in data.name) {`. Note however is not good practice to is `for in` loops on arrays

Comment: You should probably also call `$("#users").empty()` _before_ the loop. If it's in the loop as it is now, it will empty the select box on each iteration and you'll only end up with the last name.

Answer (score 1):

I would do in this way...

JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url :'frombase.php',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(data){
                    $("#users").empty();
                    $(data['options']).each(function(k,v){
                        $("#users").append("<option value='"+ v['id'] +"'>"+ v['name'] +"</option>");
                    });
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('Error of server comunication');
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP:

```
    $db = 'YOUR CONNECTION';
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM users");
    $query->execute();        
    $query->bind_result($id,$name);

    while ($query->fetch()) {
        $result[] = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name);
    }
    $root['options'] = $result;
    $root = json_encode($root);     
    $db->close();
    echo $root;
```